# Any point in thread monitor restarting a dead thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Came across the following code (modified to make my point clear):

```
class ThreadWithQueue extends Thread {
        Queue<Msg> msgQueue;
        public void run() { while (!isInterrupted()) {processMessage(queue.take());}
}             

class MessageDispatcher {
    ThreadsWithQueue[] threads;
    ...                    
    void dispatchMessage(Msg msg) {
        int index = findMatchingThread(msg);
        if (!threads[index].isAlive() || threads[index].isInterrupted()){
            try {
                threadCreateLock.lock();
                threads[index] = createAndStartThread();
            } finally {
                threadCreateLock.unlock();
            }
        }
        threads[index].queue.add(msg);
    }
```

That is, there is a 'message dispatcher' that can restart (i.e. create a new)  thread if it finds that the current one is either dead or interrupted.

Note that both classes have been written by the same author and reside in the same package.

**My question**: 
Is there any point in this 'restarting a dead thread' functionality from the design/best practices point of view? 
Wouldn't it be a better approach to just have '***catch(Throwable) {/*ignore*/}***' inside each thread's *run()* method (i.e. inside '*ThreadWithQueue.run() {...}*')?

Comment: Where do you see a dead thread being restarted? I don't know exactly where you took this code from (which is not good - you should give a link and attribute any code which is not yours on StackOverflow), but I am assuming that this starts a new thread if a thread died. Anyway, context is needed to judge whether this is good or bad.

Comment: Things like `catch(Throwable) {/*ignore*/}` are rarely a good idea, if the throwables/exceptions aren't handled they should at least be logged.

Comment: What would catching `Throwable` do in this case? Also, `catch (Throwable x) {/*ignored*/}` is literally never a good approach. Just catching `Throwable` isn't even a good idea, even if you are handling the exception, because it will catch things like `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Catching a `Throwable` should be avoided in all but very, very rare cases in which you know what you are doing (e.g. instrumentation). Let alone ignoring the caught throwable.

Comment: This is not the original code - I simplified it to give the idea. My point is this: the app will run as long as the 'MessageDispatcher' thread runs, and it re-creates the 'ThreadWithQueue' every time it dies. So essentially it is like catching a throwable inside 'ThreadWithQueue'.

Comment: It is and it isn't. In this code it's the `MessageDispatcher`s job to manage the lifecycle of the worker threads, and choose whether to restart them or not. Whereas in the other case it would be the worker thread who was in control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it might be useful to restart a thread, instead of continuing after catching and reporting the exception, when you don’t know whether the processing code has cleaned up properly in the exceptional case. Most notably, there could be `ThreadLocal` variables having associated values dangling as long as the thread is alive.

Still, there are some strange things here. Using `isInterrupted()` as a criteria for a restart doesn’t make much sense as the preceding test has proven the thread to be still alive. So it might be the case, that at some place within the `processMessage` the interruption will be used and handled, being reset when returning to the main loop. So in the end, you would have two running threads, one of them hanging forever in `queue.take()` once the queue is empty. It might be that you can preclude this scenario for the current code of `processMessage`, but then, you better stop any development of the code to be sure not to activate that time bomb in the future.

Further, there are several possible race conditions here. The thread might die *right after* `isAlive()` and `isInterrupted()` have been checked, so you’re still enqueuing to a dead thread. But since there is no attempt to transfer pending messages of a dead thread to the new thread anyway, an arbitrary number of messages may get lost when the thread dies due to an exception. Even if there was such a transfer within `dispatchMessage()`, it would imply that after the thread dies, it takes until an attempt to schedule a new message to the same thread is made, before a new thread starts processing the dangling queue. Obviously, spawning a new thread should be triggered by an exception handler if the queue is not empty, do avoid such delay.

And the rabbit hole goes even deeper. While `threads[index]` is written under the `threadCreateLock`, it is read without holding that lock, which is a broken synchronization. There are no guarantees regarding visibility of updates to the array element. A thread could read an outdated reference, creating a new thread despite another thread has already created one. Even worse, a thread could read a new reference which has not been completely initialized by the thread holding the lock. If `msgQueue` really isn’t `final`, like you have posted, a thread could encounter a `null` reference for it in that case.

I strongly recommend to use a [fixed thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) instead, which has exactly the functionality that the posted code tries to achieve, but has been written by experts understanding these pitfalls of multithreading.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Still not sure about a fixed thread pool since I need a guarantee that messages with the same ID would be handled sequentially (i.e. by the same 'threads[i]')

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any point in this 'restarting a dead thread' functionality
>   from the design/best practices point of view?

Note that the code you present starts a new thread if the old one is dead or interrupted.  Although that could arise from the the thread's `run()` throwing an unexpected exception, the particular thread will also die naturally if it is interrupted.  The latter behavior is a typical way to provide for shutting down the system.

The queuing code looks pretty natural to me.  When a message is presented to it, it ensures that the thread chosen to handle it is neither dead nor about to die before it in fact dispatches the message.

> Wouldn't it be a better
>   approach to just have `catch(Throwable) {/*ignore*/}` inside each
>   thread's `run()` method (i.e. inside `ThreadWithQueue.run() {...}`)?

Not really.  In the first place, a blanket catch and ignore policy for all types of `Throwable` is an altogether bad idea.  More particularly, what you propose would prevent an uncaught exception handler being engaged to handle such exceptions.  In the second place, as discussed above, an uncaught exception is not the only thing that could cause one of the threads to die, so what you propose would not relieve the message dispatcher from having to test for liveness and to start new threads when it finds need.

Comment: @Alexander, a thread dies when it returns from `run()`.  In your case, that will happen when its `isInterrupted()` method returns `true` when invoked in the `while` predicate.  That has nothing directly to do with exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @John. Makes sense for me, as I see a separation of responsibilities here: the 'manager'/'dispatcher' deals with any possible problems, and the 'worker' is just responsible for its job/business function and can be more ignorant of the termination conditions

Comment: It does not really *ensure* “that the thread chosen to handle it is neither dead nor about to die”, it only does a best-effort test, falling for the check-then-act anti-pattern, which will break if the condition changes right after the test…

Comment: @Alexander presumably there's user defined code running to handle a messa/ge, who knows what neck deep layers of code/libraries and whatnot it might call that could call Thread.stop() or Thread.interrupt(). The code here is just doing defensive coding where it quite effortlessly tries to handle/recover from a few bad corner cases.